# How to manage and migrate C++ libraries?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++, is there something like python-pip in C++? I am uing `json`/`YAML` packages in my 1st project, I want to know which is the correct way to manage dependencies in my project, and after I finished developing, which is the correct way to migrate dependencies to production environment?

Comment: What "packages"? In C++ you have either static libraries (statically linked into your executable) or dynamic libraries (which you can just copy into the folder of your executable)

Comment: like this :[my-json-dependency](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)

Comment: There is no equivalent to python's python-pip.  You are going get the "dev" packages the way you would get any other package for your distribution. For example pacman on Arch or apt-get/synaptic for Debian based systems.

Comment: Also, you will need to add -ljson or -l<library> to your compiler flags.

Comment: thanks, I see now!

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't have a standard package manager or build system: this is one of the major pain points of the language. You have a few options:

- Manually install dependencies when required.
- Use your OS's package manager.
- Adopt a third-party package manager such as [conan.io](http://conan.io).

None of the above solutions is perfect and dependency management will likely always require some more effort on your part compared to languages such as Python or Rust.

Comment: You forgot "ditch the language for another" :)

Comment: 5th - write your own language

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no central library management system in C++ similar to `pip`. You need to download and install the packages you need manually or through some package manager if your OS supports it.

As for managing multiple libraries in a C++ project, you could use [CMAKE](https://cmake.org/) or something similar. If you link your libraries dynamically (i.e., though .dll or .so files), then you need to supply these dynamic library binaries along with your application. To find out which dll files may be needed, you could something like the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) or [ELF Library Viewer](http://www.purinchu.net/software/elflibviewer.php).

Personally, I use a development environment - specifically [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) (with the QtCreator), containing many of these components like `qmake` etc. - which simplifies the process of development and distribution.